# MAX + GROUP BY в Django ORM (вывод последней записи для каждой группы)

Tags: sql, django, django-orm

Есть модель

```
class Bid(...):
  contractor = ...
  pub_date = ...
  ...
```

В базе данных представляется таким образом

```
id | contractor | pub_date
 1 | 1          | 2016-08-20
 2 | 1          | 2016-08-21
 3 | 1          | 2016-08-30
 4 | 2          | 2016-08-20
 5 | 2          | 2016-08-29
```

Нужно получить по **последней** записи для каждого `contractor`.

Насколько понимаю, в SQL это делается просто (в своих знаниях SQL не уверен, но **вроде бы** это запрос срабатывает, как мне надо):

```
SELECT id, MAX(pub_date), contractor FROM bid GROUP BY contractor;
```

Выводит:

```
 id | contractor | pub_date
  3 | 1          | 2016-08-30
  5 | 2          | 2016-08-29
```

А как это сделать с помощью Django ORM?

Answer (score 1):

На сколько мне известно, получить точно такой же результат с помощью ORM невозможно. Наиболее близкий способ:

```
 Bid.objects.values('contractor').annotate(latest_date=Max('pub_date'))
```

Comment: Этот запрос выводит лишь `contractor` и `latest_date`, а меня как раз интересовал`id` сущности, которая соответствуют этому отношению. В любом случае, спасибо.

Comment: Как я и написал, это единственный способ группировки в Django ORM.

Answer (score 0):

Вы хотите получить `id` соответствующий наибольшему `pub_date`, он же скорее всего будет наибольшим и последним значением `id` в группе.

Однако этот SQL запрос некорректен во многих СУБД:

```sql
SELECT id, MAX(pub_date), contractor FROM bid GROUP BY contractor;
```

В Postgres приведёт к такой ошибке:

> `id` must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Т.к при группировке-агрегации все указанные в `SELECT` поля должны быть или ключами группировки, или агрегированными значениями. Можно исправить следующим образом:

```sql
SELECT MAX(id), MAX(pub_date), contractor FROM bid GROUP BY contractor;
```

Соответственно, на Python с Django ORM это будет так:

```py
Bid.objects.values('contractor').annotate(last_date=Max('pub_date'), last_id=Max('pub_date'))
```

Но так мы получим QuerySet со словарями, в то время как можно было бы получить сами объекты модели. Для этого нужно избавиться от группировки в SQL и метода `.values(...)` в Питоне заменив на аннотацию с оконной функцией:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY contractor
            ORDER BY pub_date DESC
        ) AS ord
    FROM bid
)
WHERE ord = 1
```

```py
Bid.objects.all() \
    .annotate(
        ord=Window(
            expression=RowNumber(),
            partition_by=F('contractor'),
            order_by=[F("pub_date").desc()]
        )
    ) \
    .filter(ord=1)
```